# React Native - Android app restarts on background

Tags: android, react-native, background, restart

My react-native android app restarts on background even in AdMob ads.

I newly added Google-AdMob ads to my app but when I take it to the background or watch Interstitial ads in the app, it restarts and starts over from the splash screen.

```
"dependencies": 
"firebase": "^5.0.4",
"native-base": "^2.4.3",
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "0.55.3",
"react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
"react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
"react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
"react-native-share": "^1.0.27",
"react-native-storage": "^0.2.2",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
"react-native-video": "^2.0.0",
"react-native-view-shot": "^2.4.0",
"react-navigation": "^1.5.11",
"tty": "^1.0.1"

"devDependencies": 
"babel-jest": "22.4.3",
"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
"jest": "22.4.3",
"react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
```

Comment: There may be a memory leak in the app , try debugging it and optimize the component. I personally like to use only one banner of admob globally

Comment: What do you mean memory leak? How can it be detected and how can it be fixed. I am not a pro of neither Android development nor react-native. I just used components above, also I am using 1 banner in screens and one interstitial in the usage.